# Measure text ranges for TextRenderer

Tags: c#, winapi, unicode, gdi

I have a custom control which renders text, including word wrap, using System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString().  Part of the rendering includes drawing highlight, such as a background color, or an underline, or other decoration on specified ranges of the text.

```
void HighlightRegion(Graphics g, string text, int startPos, int length, RectangleF region, Font font, StringFormat sf, Color c)
{
    var range = new CharacterRange[1];
    range[0].First = startPos;
    range[0].Length = length;
    sf.SetMeasureableCharacterRanges(range);
    var ranges = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, region, sf);
    using (ranges[0])
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(c))
    {
         g.FillRegion(brush, ranges[0]);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I discovered that Graphics.DrawString doesn't handle font fallbacks properly.  I was making sure it could handle Unicode, and testing with emojis showed that they render as little boxes.  I found, however, that System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText() handles font fallback correctly.  So I've been experimenting with changing the text rendering to use TextRenderer.DrawText().  But I can't figure out the range highlighting portion.

TextRenderer.MeasureText works fine for calculating the entire text size, but there doesn't seem to be any way to measure just a portion of it.  A range of characters could start in the middle of a line, wrap around to the next line, and continue on.  Trying to predict where those characters would fall would mean exactly reproducing the word wrap logic that TextRenderer uses internally.

I've looked into P/Invoke of GDI GetCharacterPlacementW (no word wrap), I've looked into Uniscribe (no built-in font fallback), I've considered measuring character by character (messy, and I'm likely to get edge cases wrong, and I have to somehow match the built in word wrap), but they all have issues.  Is there a correct way to measure a TextRenderer.DrawText range?  Or should I just take over the rendering process entirely and lay out the text character by character?

Comment: I have something working decently well by measuring each character and doing my own word wrapping, and then drawing 1 line at a time.  But Unicode is so complex, I'm sure there are tons of special cases I haven't handled properly.

Comment: I believe what you are supposed to do is use `GetCharacterPlacementW` with GCP_MAXEXTENT`, and do the layout for multiline text (including word wrap) manually. Not a recommendation, just what I have come to believe is the "intended route".